# Android - Send values from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I'm a beginner on Android and I have already read several topics on this issue, but I can not get this to work on my app.

I've two layouts :

1. activity_home (android:id="@+id/home_container")
2. activity_signs (android:id="@+id/signs_container").

I've two Activities :

1. HomeActivity, nothing special :

   `public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.home_container, new HomeFragment())
           .commit();
       }
   }`
2. SignsActivity, where I want to save my values when rotating the smartphone :

   `public class SignsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_signs);
           if (savedInstanceState == null) {
               SignsFragment signsFragment = new SignsFragment();
               signsFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.signs_container, signsFragment, "SIGNS_FRAGMENT_TAG")
               .commit();
           } else {
               SignsFragment signsFragment =
                   (SignsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentByTag("SIGNS_FRAGMENT_TAG");
           }
       }
   }`

I've two Fragments :

1. HomeFragment, where I want to send data :

   `public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
       String language;
       public HomeFragment() {
           // Required empty public constructor
       }
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
           ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home,
               container, false);
           language = "french";
           Button displayView = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.display);
           if (displayView != null) {
               displayView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       EditText signView = (EditText) 
                           rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_number);
                       String signNumber = signView.getText().toString();
                       if (!signNumber.equals("")) {
                           int number = Integer.parseInt(signNumber);
                           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                           bundle.putString("language", language);
                           bundle.putInt("signNumber", number);
                           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                               getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                               .beginTransaction();
                           SignsFragment signsFragment = new SignsFragment();
                           signsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.signs_container,
                               signsFragment);
                           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                           fragmentTransaction.commit();
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
           return rootView;
       }
   }`
2. SignsFragment, where I want to receive data :

   `public class SignsFragment extends Fragment {
       private String language;
       private int signNumber;
       private View rootView;
       public SignsFragment() {
           // Required empty public constructor
       }
       @Override
       public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
           super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
           outState.putString("language", language);
           outState.putInt("signNumber", signNumber);
       }
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           Bundle bundle = getArguments();
           if (bundle != null) {
               language = bundle.getString("language");
               signNumber = bundle.getInt("signNumber", 1);
           } else {
               if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                   // Restore last state
                   language = savedInstanceState.getString("language");
                   signNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("signNumber");
               } else {
                   language = "french";
                   signNumber = 1;
               }
           }
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_signs, container,
               false);
       }
   }`

The app closes when I click the button on the home, while I want to retrieve the data in signs. Can anyone help me correct my mistake ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Use Local broadcast

Answer (score 0):

I have one fragment, in which I have two Tabs, Which are again fragments. So i am moving from one tab to another tab and passing data. Here is the code. This Works Perfectly

```
  // write below code in Second Fragment from where you want to pass the values to nextFragment(i-e FirstFragment)
 // Write below code in OnClickListener of the button in secondFragment
  if (tablayout.getTabAt(1).isSelected()) { // here one is the index number of second fragment i-e current fragment
  LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
  Intent i = new Intent("EDIT_TAG_REFRESH");
  i.putExtra("Key1",value1);
  i.putExtra("Key2",value2);
  lbm.sendBroadcast(i);
   }
   tablayout.getTabAt(0).select(); // here 0 is the index number of first fragment i-e to whch fragment it has to move
```

// Write below code in First Fragment

```
MyReceiver post_r;
Context context;
String newValue;
public void refresh() {
    //your code in refresh.
    Log.i("PostRefresh", "Post:YES");
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(post_r);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    post_r = new MyReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(post_r,
            new IntentFilter("EDIT_TAG_REFRESH"));
}
  // OnResuming get the details from second Fragment
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        YourFirstFragment.this.refresh(); // presend Fragment Name

        String action = intent.getAction();
        st_value1= intent.getStringExtra("Key1");
        st_value2= intent.getStringExtra("Key2");
       // EITHER SET THE VALUES HERE OR IN REFERESH METHOD

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tara,

I tried, but I don't know how to receive the local broadcast.
When I click on the button, nothing happens.
I stay on the homepage, but the app doesn't close anymore.

Comment: what is your requirement? I did this in on TabSelected.

Comment: `private Context mContext;
    ...
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mContext = context;
            SignsFragment.this.refresh();
            language = intent.getStringExtra("language");
            signNumber = intent.getIntExtra("signNumber", 1);
        }
    }`

Did I do well ?

Comment: you just need to pass the "key" not "value" as how we do in shared preferences.

Comment: I want to click on the button, and send the data of the edittext from the first layout for use for a display in a second layout.

I don't know how to receive the data and display the second layout with the SignsFragment.

Comment: Of course, like this :

    `language = intent.getStringExtra("language");
     signNumber = intent.getIntExtra("signNumber", 1); `

Comment: signNumber = intent.getIntExtra("signNumber", 1); why you wre writing 1 here?

Comment: getIntExtra needs two values : the key and a default value.
But I still need to display the activity_signs layout with the data it receives.

Comment: put 0 instead of 1

Comment: Hello Tara,

Thank you for trying to help me. I don't understand why it can be helpful to change the default value in the second parameter, but I tried and nothing has changed.

I already made an intent between activities before creating the fragments and it worked perfectly. I just want to send data in the same way, but between fragments now. I've tried FragmentTransaction and Bundle as I've shown it in my question, and I don't know how to receive a localbroadcast and display its data ...

Someone has an idea to correct my code ?